# how to add link in react tailwind?

Tags: html, reactjs, npm, tailwind-css

I am create project using react & tailwind. I would like to redirect user on next page once click on link.
I try `<a />` tag but couldn't see any difference between `<p />` and `<a />` tags. I need to download any npm pakage?

Answer (score 1):

yes, `<p />` and `<a />` both tags are looks like same without classes but both have own properties. You need to add class in `<a />` tags. Like,
`<a href="your_link" className="text-blue-400">redirect</a>`